# Device orientation in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to develop app for both device orientation(portrait and landscape) in flutter. When I rotate my device in landscape, app size will adjust on landscape. If I rotate my device in portrait, app size will adjust on portrait.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple called as "responsive design", please have a look to one of the best post about the same subject ;

https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-and-orientations-in-flutter-fragments-in-flutter-a4c51b849434

and also from the original source from Flutter documentation ;

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

you can develop two widgets for each orientation each one has different sizes of text, padding.... using **MediaQuery.of(context).orientation** to get the current orientation or you can use **Layout Builder**.

Otherwise, you can lock your app to a specific orientation:

```
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

 main() {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
     runApp(MyHomePage());
 }
```